# AEM workflow auto advance timeout not working.

Tags: workflow, aem

I wrote a custom workflow. Where I have setted absoluteTime to workflow metadata and using auto advance timeout ootb step before activation of page. But page is publish immediately please help me where I am wrong.

Comment: please refer to this page [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this user has created another duplicate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571271/absolutetimeautoadvancer-not-working-in-aem-6-3